# Как сделать id по порядку с 1?

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

У меня в БД есть колонка `id` с `A_I`. Он не повторяется никогда. Как сделать колонку (`cid`, допустим), в которой будут значения всегда с 1 и далее по порядку (1, 2, 3). Точнее будет сказать как пересчитывать `id` в этой колонке при удалении, например, строки где-нибудь по середине.

Comment: Это полный бред если выводы и привязки идут по ID. А это практически всегда.

Сделай тогда колонку без AI. и руками смотри и проверяй, ну и удаляй и пересчитывай.

Comment: @Shrek Так колонка cid без A_I. Вот я и спрашиваю, как правильно пересчитывать?

Comment: Нужно правильно формулировать свои вопросы. из того что написано выше - ответ должен быть именно такой!

Answer (score 1):

На то они и id, что они не должны меняться. Пока у Вас одна таблица, это ещё не понятно, но когда есть много связанных таблиц, то обновление id по всем таблицам (для поддержания ссылочной целостности), может оказаться далеко не тривиальной задачей.

Если ещё не совсем представляете, то представим такую задачу. Пусть есть новостной портал, где есть таблица со списком новостей (там же и название и текст), а также таблица с комментариями к статьям. Сайт работает, нагруженный, все ок. И тут решили удалить самую первую новость ( с кем не бывает). В случае, если id не нужно пересчитывать, то нужно будет удалить одну запись в первой таблице, и несколько в второй. И скорость этого удаления в современных базах не зависит от размера базы сильно. При этом даже таблицу блокировать на долго не нужно.

В случае, если нужно пересчитать id, то придется обновить все записи и все комментарии (не забываем, мы решили удалить первую новость). Это уже очень сильно зависит от размера базы (в лучшем случае линейно). Но не забываем о пользователях, которые в этот момент открыли новости. Нажал человек f5,  а у него другая статья (ведь новости скорее всего будут  иметь урл вида "сайт/news/номер"). Но это вот писал человек комментарий, нажал отправить, а он попал к другой статье.

Конечно, можно написать кучу кода, который все это разрулит, но зачем?

Поэтому, правильный ответ - не нужно его (id) пересчитывать.

Comment: Мне нужно для другого. У меня есть список контактов. Там табличкой выводится, в которой есть колонка ID. Если выводить из столбца id, то получается у нас номеруется так: 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 15 и т.д. А мне надо 1, 2, 3...

Comment: А не нужно эту колонку выводить. А если нужна нумерация, так никто не мешает ее добавить.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, ваше поле `AUTO INCREMENT`.
Пересчет ваших ID - задача может и простая, но больно уж ненужная. Возможно вы боитесь, что когда-нибудь закончится ваш `AUTO INCREMENT`.
Не проще ли определять незанятые ID. И уже добавлять записи с незанятым ID, заодно ваша последовательность, которая вам так нужна, заполнится значениями 1, 2, 3...