# Пересчет auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql

Есть скрипт новостей, к примеру. Есть таблица с id (primary), заголовок, текст, дата и т.д. Есть новость id 1, id 2, id 6 (3,4,5 удалены ранее по той или иной причине). Как пересчитать id? Чтобы после этого были id 1 2 3?

Comment: Тут правильнее спрашивать не "как?", а "зачем?". И тогда правильным ответом будет "незачем".

Comment: @Yaant Согласен. Но вдруг ответ будет "очень хочется", тогда и вопрос интересным становится :) Тут вот коллега уже и ответ написал

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/125644/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-id-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-1

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В указанном вами вопросе не дан ответ как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SET @i :=0");
mysql_query("UPDATE `news` SET  `id` = (@i := @i + 1)");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `news` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
```

Может как-нибудь так?

Comment: Только вы не учли.... что если будут номера в таблице `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` и  удалить `3,4,5,6`.  Потом ввести ваш код... номера пересчитаются... а новая запись в таблице будет с номером `8`.....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `ALTER TABLE news AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

Comment: @splash58 мне это ни к чему писать. не я задавал вопрос и не я отвечал... причем в какой момент этот альтер делать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский может, остальным это неинтересно, а вы спрашивали :)

Comment: @splash58 а по вашему какой смысл в пересчете `auto_increment` столбца если он остается по сути старым? только ради пересчета `id`? вряд ли

Comment: @Cladoxylon можно и 1 - не будет переписывать, будет дырки заполнять :)

Comment: @Cladoxylon что-то ваш код не работает...) Автоинкремент не пересчитывается

Comment: @АлексейШиманский теперь работает, минус можете убрать ;)

Comment: @Cladoxylon это не мой минус

Answer (score 2):

Так как ответ на вопрос: "Как пересчитать id AUTO_INCREMENT" в 98% случаев будет: не нужно этого делать и куча доводов в пользу этого (что, в принципе правильно), то приведу текст из ответа в этом вопросе: [Как сделать id по порядку с 1?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/125644/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-id-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-1)

Цитата:

> На то они и id, что они не должны меняться. Пока у Вас одна таблица,
>   это ещё не понятно, но когда есть много связанных таблиц, то
>   обновление id по всем таблицам (для поддержания ссылочной
>   целостности), может оказаться далеко не тривиальной задачей.
>
> Если ещё не совсем представляете, то представим такую задачу. Пусть
>   есть новостной портал, где есть таблица со списком новостей (там же и
>   название и текст), а также таблица с комментариями к статьям. Сайт
>   работает, нагруженный, все ок. И тут решили удалить самую первую
>   новость ( с кем не бывает). В случае, если id не нужно пересчитывать,
>   то нужно будет удалить одну запись в первой таблице, и несколько в
>   второй. И скорость этого удаления в современных базах не зависит от
>   размера базы сильно. При этом даже таблицу блокировать на долго не
>   нужно.
>
> В случае, если нужно пересчитать id, то придется обновить все записи и
>   все комментарии (не забываем, мы решили удалить первую новость). Это
>   уже очень сильно зависит от размера базы (в лучшем случае линейно). Но
>   не забываем о пользователях, которые в этот момент открыли новости.
>   Нажал человек f5, а у него другая статья (ведь новости скорее всего
>   будут иметь урл вида "сайт/news/номер"). Но это вот писал человек
>   комментарий, нажал отправить, а он попал к другой статье.
>
> Конечно, можно написать кучу кода, который все это разрулит, но зачем?
>
> Поэтому, правильный ответ - не нужно его (id) пересчитывать.

---

Если все банально и нет каких-либо зависимостей, простая табличка, в которой пересчет ни на что не повлияет, то можно попробовать следующее:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY `id` INT(11); 
ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP PRIMARY KEY; 
UPDATE `table_name` SET `id`='0'; 
ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

1. Убиваем инкремент.
2. Убиваем первичный ключ.
3. Обнуляем значения полей.
4. Устанавливаем значение инкремента.
5. Включаем инкремент.

Answer (score 1):

Удивительно не то, что этот вопрос задают.

И даже не то, что на него отвечают.

Удивительно, что даже те, кто вроде бы понимает, какой адский ад этот вопрос, не могут толком объяснить - почему. Единственное объяснение - это какой-то лепет про блокировку таблицы.

И почему-то никто не может привести простой пример с поиском новости по id. Если у нас, к примеру, картинки были привязаны к новости с ид=7, то теперь они будут показываться к совсем другой новости. Если были комментарии - они так же пойдут в том же направлении.

Я могу понять, что средний пользователь пхп чудовищно далёк от программирования и ему в принципе недоступно понятие **реляционной базы данных** - то есть такой базы, в которой таблицы связаны между собой, с помощью не **имеющего никакого физического смысла, абстрактного уникального идентификатора.** Но вот почему этому среднему пользователю дают отвечать и потом еще плюсуют его ответы - вот этого я никогда не пойму.

Comment: Вроде бы про связь таблицы с чем-либо еще, к примеру к комментариям - описано в моем ответе в цитате..Я специально это поместил все в начало. Или вы решили сразу всех заминусовать ничего не читая?)