# Массовая замена id на порядковые номера

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Поясню вопрос. Есть mysql-таблица `table` в которой в столбце id (он AUTO_INCREMENT, просто некоторые записи удалялись) цифры идут не по порядку, а с разрывами, т.е. 1,4,10,11,23,27,28,34 и т.д. Необходимо всем строчкам присвоить id по порядку, т.е. 1,2,3,4,5 и т.д. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать?

Comment: зачем? есть нумерация а есть и уникальные id

Comment: Внешние ключи к этим id есть или нету?

Comment: @Naumov ну вот надо) айди должен стать нумерацией в моём случае

Comment: @andreymal нету

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ -

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN id;
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN (`id` int key auto_increment);
```

Comment: спасибо, всё верно

Comment: @АлександрВладимирович Один маленький момент. Данная манипуляция может повредить данные!

Comment: Если данная манипуляция будет проделана, то автор получит ожидаемый результат. Ответ правильный! Но данная манипуляция опасна(может повредить данные), дорога(Время выполнения на большой таблице) и бесполезна(Пользы от неё нет). Поэтому минус.

Comment: @E_p почему бы вам тогда не предложить альтернативное решение? Я думаю, это полезно в рамках сайта, и наоборот приветствуется.

Comment: @Denis В коментарии Алексея Шиманского приложенна ссылка с правильным ответом(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480632/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-auto-increment#480675). К сожалению, как и в этом вопросе автор выбрал неправильный ответ. Не вижу смысла повторяться.

Comment: @Denis ПС: Отметил вопрос как дубликат.

Comment: @E_p извиняюсь, не увидел комментарии к вопросу :)